WiFi card will appear to work for a moment before breaking entirely
(EDIT: I have since found a work-around for this, I just switched from Linux Mint to Bookworm Puppy Linux and that fixed the issue. The problem still happens on Mint though.)
I'm fixing up an old hand-me-down PC. For a while the WiFi worked just fine, then one day it stopped and has been doing the same thing since: when I boot up the PC it will see the available networks nearby and start to connect to my home WiFi, but after 10 or so seconds it will say it couldn't connect, and checking the settings all the WiFi networks disappeared.
This has been happening for a while and I've tried to figure out what exactly is going wrong, turning WiFi off/on again, checking lshw -class network, nmcli, and inxi -n and they all say its disabled for some reason. I can give the full outputs of those if need be but Ill skip for now for brevity.
The notable thing that im actually asking about is this: when checking dmesg I get this: (i know the mac address isnt really sensitive info, I just want to be careful)
[   37.339965] wlp1s0: authenticate with 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 (local address=[WIFI CARD MAC ADDRESS])
[   37.339979] wlp1s0: send auth to 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 (try 1/3)
[   37.342122] wlp1s0: authenticated
[   37.343256] wlp1s0: associate with 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 (try 1/3)
[   37.344353] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[   37.344494] wlp1s0: associated
[   37.374328] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 36 (36 - 0) dBm as advertised by 80:03:84:3e:44:c8
[   44.179341] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[   44.179347] DMAR: [DMA Read NO_PASID] Request device [01:00.0] fault addr 0xfff56000 [fault reason 0x06] PTE Read access is not set
[   47.639898] wlp1s0: authenticate with 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 (local address=[WIFI CARD MAC ADDRESS])
[   47.639905] wlp1s0: send auth to 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 (try 1/3)
[   48.795263] wlp1s0: send auth to 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 (try 2/3)
[   49.755406] wlp1s0: send auth to 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 (try 3/3)
[   49.955566] wlp1s0: authentication with 80:03:84:3e:44:c8 timed out


I think the DMAR: ... lines are important here but I don't know what any of it means, the errors or acronyms. Is there a way I can fix this or is the card just busted and I need to get a new one?
EDIT: I said it wouldnt connect to wifi regardless of OS, I just tried Windows 10 again and its working just fine, sorry I thought I checked that already. Device Manager says that everything is working fine so Im not sure why its not working on Linux Mint.
EDIT 2: Got the wifi working fine on BookwormPup64 Puppy Linux as well, so I think its just a Mint problem
System Information
PC Model: Dell OptiPlex 9020
CPU: Intel i7-4790S (8) @ 4.000GHz
OS: Linux Mint 22 (Cinnamon)

You state the issue occurs, "regardless of OS", yet you only show Linux Mint 22 (Cinnamon). It's not uncommon for some Linux distros to not have correct drivers for some NIC devices, particularly Realtek. What is the NIC make and model? What other OS have you tried?

its a RAK-RT5390, Ive tried Ubuntu 24.04, I think also Windows 10 but Im not sure on that.

I might be wrong in parts of my statement, but I think Windows can help diagnose the Wi-Fi card. Try installing Windows on your PC, then pulling up Device Manager and looking for problems with the Wi-Fi card. Edit your question to include some of the Device Manager info as that might be able to help us further.
If you can, please add info on all of the OSes you tried using to diagnose the issue too.

ok good to know! I'll try that right now, thankfully ive already got the W10 iso so this shouldnt take too long

Not a solution, but I believe DMAR is DMA Remapping and older drivers'hardware may not like this. I also believe that DMA remapping is now default for popular distros, so maybe look into that. Some mention  IOMMU=pt (passthrough) for intel might provide relief and  IOMMU and DMAR are linked. See for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/iommu-dma-remapping

@Yorik that actually helps a lot! I had no idea what those meant and couldnt find anything online so thats good to know. Thanks a ton!
